# One Way Anova giving wrong P value

Tags: anova, p-value, percentage

I have 8 columns of data for cumulative percentages and I performed one way anova. I know 4 sets of the data are statistically different because it is someone else's research data. When I added my own 4 sets of data, the result showed p value of 0.4. It didn't sound right so I tested only the 4 original data and it gave a high p value again, though I already know it shouldn't.

Here is the result of Anova for the original 4 data sets that I performed, but in the original article, the second picture, SS, df, and mean square are the same as mine but F and P value are different.
[image]

[image]

I appreciate it if anyone knows what is wrong. I compared the data 2 by 2 with T test and each showed a very low P value, but the very same 2 data sets show a high P value in Anova.
I tried both excel and SPSS and came with the same result.

Comment: The bottom image is a *two-way* ANOVA.